# Difference between @SpringApplicationConfiguration and @ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, junit, configuration

What is the Difference between `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` and `@ContextConfiguration` with respect to JUnit test cases?

Answer (score 7):

`@ContextConfiguration` is an annotation from the Spring Test Framework, which is suitable for every Spring application, `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is from Spring Boot and is actually a composite annotation, which includes `ContextConfiguration` with the custom `SpringApplicationContextLoader` as loader.

Answer (score 6):

`@ContextConfiguration` and `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` both are doing same. Both load and configure an ApplicationContext for integration tests. But `@ContextConfiguration` has some lacking for support.

### @ContextConfiguration Supported Resource Types

Prior to `Spring 3.1`, only path-based resource locations (typically XML configuration files) were supported. As of Spring 3.1, context loaders may choose to support either path-based or class-based resources.

As of Spring 4.0.4, context loaders may choose to support path-based and class-based resources simultaneously. Consequently `@ContextConfiguration` can be used to declare either path-based resource locations (via the locations() or value() attribute) or annotated classes (via the classes() attribute).

> Note, however, that most implementations of SmartContextLoader only
>   support a single resource type. As of Spring 4.1, path-based resource
>   locations may be either XML configuration files or Groovy scripts (if
>   Groovy is on the classpath). Of course, third-party frameworks may
>   choose to support additional types of path-based resources.

`@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is similar to the standard `@ContextConfiguration` but **uses Spring Boot's SpringApplicationContextLoader**.

### Resource Link:

1. [Annotation Type SpringApplicationConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.html)
2. [Annotation Type ContextConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html?is-external=true)

Answer (score 2):

- **@ContextConfiguration**

  - Loads the Spring application context
  - it doesn’t load it with the full Spring Boot treatment.
- **@SpringApplicationConfiguration**

  - largely identical to @ContextConfiguration.
  - Loads the Spring application context,

    - but also enables logging, the loading of external properties (application.properties or application.yml).
  - At most part @SpringApplicationConfiguration replaces @ContextConfiguration when writing tests for Spring Boot applications.